# Where is State Monad in Haskell, and how can I use it?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm learning State Monad, and was told it doesn't exist any more, the first question is why Haskell remove it?

and when I using

```hs
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type State s = StateT s Identity
```

I get

```hs
Ambiguous occurrence ‘State’
    It could refer to
       either ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.State’
           or ‘Main.State’,
```

but when I tried `:t State`, I find nothing. 
This is self-contradictory, I wonder whether it exists or not?

finally, I write it by my self

```hs
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

but I alse need some other function like `put`, `get`... where are they.

using `:i get`, I found `MonadState`, is this the new implement of  `State`?

Comment: Yes, the `State` type constructor doesn't exist anymore. Instead you use the `state` function which resides in the `MonadState` type class. For more check [Control.Monad.State.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html)

Comment: You say that you were told the state monad “doesn’t exist any more”. I think it’s worth pointing out that this isn’t entirely correct. `State` as a standalone monad doesn’t exist any more, but a `State` monad still exists; however, it’s defined in terms of another `StateT` monad instead of being implemented as a separate monad of its own. This new state monad lives in the `Control.Monad.Trans.State` module, in the `transformers` library. **EDIT:** I’ve just noticed you are already aware of `Control.Monad.Trans.State` — sorry for the redundant comment!

Answer (score 12):

> I get Ambiguous occurrence

Really, let's try the code you posted..

```
cat <<EOF >umi.hs
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type State s = StateT s Identity
EOF
ghci umi.hs
```

We get

```
Ok, one module loaded.
```

So that's actually fine.  I suspect you have more code that tries to use `State` but it is ambiguous because you have imported a `State` and do not need to define your own `State` type.

> When I tried :t State, I find nothing. This is self-contradictory

When you try `:t State` you get more than nothing, you get:

```
:t State

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Data constructor not in scope: State
```

Read that carefully, it says "Data constructor" not "type" or "type constructor".  You can't check the type of a type (`:t` is short of `:type`).  You can, however, use info:

```
> :i State
type Control.Monad.Trans.State.State s =
  StateT s Identity :: * -> *
        -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy’

type Main.State s = StateT s Identity :: * -> *
        -- Defined at umi.hs:4:5
```

So you see, your (`Main`s) type alias is redundant of the type alias you imported from `Control.Monad.Trans.State`.  Solution? Just don't define your type alias.

EDIT: The above was intended to clear up some misunderstandings.  Answering your actual questions here.

> Where is state monad

There are many State monads defined in Haskell libraries.  The most popular one is in `Control.Monad.Trans.State` from the `transformers` package which you have already found.  There's also a the `monadlib` version of State, and the entirely different `MonadState` class (in the `mtl` package) which is a pair of get and set operations for any monad that has some notion of state.

> and how can I use it?

Well you import the module and you can `runState stateMonadicOperation initialState`:

```
> runState (mapM (\x -> state $ \s -> (x,s+x)) [1..4])  9
([1,2,3,4],19)
```

There are a lot of state monad questions you can find here on stackoverflow if you have specific questions.

> I wonder whether it exists or not?

This depends on the `it` in your question.  There is a `State` type constructor but no `State` data constructor.

> using :i get, I found MonadState, is this the new implement of State?

No.  `State` the monad is defined in the tranformers as :

```
type State s = StateT s Data.Functor.Identity.Identity :: * -> *
newtype StateT s (m :: * -> *) a
  = StateT {runStateT :: s -> m (a, s)}
```

So there is a transformer with a data constructor and a type alias of the transformer and identity monad.

In contrast, the MonadState is just an abstraction of the ability to get and set values:

```
class Monad m => MonadState s (m :: * -> *) | m -> s where
  get :: m s
  put :: s -> m ()
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out explicitly that under the monad transformer definition, `runState` is, rather than a field name in a specific `State` type, just a function defined as `\m -> runIdentity . runStateT m`, to hide the necessary unwrapping of the `Identity` value that `StateT` produces.

Comment: love your little mapM runstate example!